# Vuetify theme changes to default on page reload or navigation to another page in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-btn @click="toggleTheme">toggle theme</v-btn>
    ...
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import { useTheme } from 'vuetify'

export default {
  setup () {
    const theme = useTheme()

    return {
      theme,
      toggleTheme: () => theme.global.name.value = theme.global.current.value.dark ? 'light' : 'dark'
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

I implemented the above example, But when navigating to another page the theme which is set goes back to default.

I tried using store.js to save the state but since setup() is called again at navigation, the theme resets to default. What the best way to solve this in Vue3.